# Reference for study about good teachers in a US state

Tags: secondary-education, reference-request, usa

Several years ago I have read about a study in a US state where standard test scores were used to identify teachers whose students consistently improved far above the average and then film and analyse their teaching for common traits.

An important aspect was that these teachers were quite different in many respects. However, quite a few commonalities were identified.

I would really like a reference for this study if someone recognizes it.

Comment: Do you have an idea in what decade the study was conducted?

Comment: I think that it should be between 10 and 20 years ago.